Is it possible to create 2 A records alias and ip in AWS Route53 for the same record name?
I have the following use case:
I have a system in which I serve both the web and api via one ec2 instance with public ip.
I have a single Route53 A type record pointing to the EIP of the ec2 instance.
As the application grows I want to move to a more scalable architecture that uses AWS ALB.
I have created the alb and configured everything so it points to the new ec2 instances one for api one for web etc.
The thing is, I want to do this with 0 downtime and want to keep both A records in round-robin for 2-3 days then remove the A record of the EC2.
I tried this both with terragrunt and also manually in the Route53 UI and do get:
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: Tried to create resource record set [name='web.secret.', type='A'] but it already exists)
My goal is to have one A record of type alias pointing to the loadbalancer dns and one A record pointing to the ip of the existing ec2 This way requests round-robin and some users use the alb some the ec2 which both are up then I remove the ec2 ip record and leave all traffic go to the alb.

Yes, this is possible via Weighted routing policy.
Simply create 2 records with Weighted as a Routing policy and assign them unique Record IDs while keeping the subdomain same.
To distribute traffic, assign weights based on your need. Let say you want to send 70% of the traffic to ALB and 30% to the EC2. Then add a weight of 70 in ALBs records and 30 in EC2s record.

Hi, I am testing Record Type A with Alias and Weight and cannot find a way to set both ec2 ip and alb dns+zoneid

@KristiJorgji you need to create 2 separate records. one for ALB DNS and one for EC2 IP.

If I try to create 2 separate records one A ALIAS for ALB Dns-zoneid, then try to create A Record Ip for ec2 do get the error that I posted. I am trying again deleting those both and trying to create "weighted" from scratch manually and later with terragrut

@KristiJorgji yes, you won't get this issue if you do it via Weighted.

I am trying to find a way to use existing record into the weighted withot deleting existing one. I got one time error already exist. I don't want to delete the existing A Ec2 ip record as for some minutes will result in downtime until I define the weighted..

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
